# Historical Linguistics: Merging consonants

Tags: historical-linguistics, sound-change

In Middle Egyptian (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_language#Phonology), the /s/ and /z/ merged into one sound, but the graphemes continued to be used interchangeably. 
As one who is interested in historical linguistics (or should I say diacronic linguistics?) I was wondering in which way the phonological merger rule could be applied to make this clear.

Sorry if I was unclear before :)

Comment: In what context are you wanting to "show" the sound change?

Comment: in the context of sound change. Take the example a > e/V_V.

Comment: You need to figure out (or at least make a theory about) what the sound change actually is.  There is no special sort of sound change that happens only when you have incomplete information about the sounds before and after the change.  The state of your knowledge can't have an historical effect.

Answer (score 1):

You have apparently taken a position on the phonetic value of the sound sometimes written as [z], that it is voiced. The alternative is that it is an "emphatic", though that raises questions as to the phonetic nature of emphatics (i..e were they pharyngealized or were they ejective?). Given the assumption that the phoneme is phonetically realized as *z*, the rule would apply just to the "voiced alveolar fricative". It is plausible that the other potential voiced fricatives <ꜣ,ꜥ> were not fricatives but rather were approximants, i.e. sonorants, in which case one could just express the change as devoicing of fricatives (regardless of place of articulation).

If you instead adopt the emphatic interpretation of "z", you would essentially have the same rule, replacing "voiced" with "emphatic" and "voiceless" with "non-emphatic".

Answer (score 1):

I will tackle the question "How to show this as a sound change".

There are several methods available:

- Study borrowings from Egypt to other languages (Especially the names of rulers and other important persons). When the other language has a contrast between s/z, but doesn't apply it to Egyptian loan words we can interpret this as a hint of a sound change in Egyptian
- Study borrowings from other languages to Egypt. When there is a confusion around s/z from other languages we can interpret this as a hint that Egyptian does not maintain the distinction any longer
- Internal evidence. Watch the development of Egypt spelling. When the formerly distinct letter for s and z are confounded, we see this as evidence that their distinction is no longer maintained in the spoken language.
- Observations from ancient grammaticians. When we are lucky we have surviving old texts describing the language change. We are in this situation for the sound change of Ancient Greek eta to ita, I don't know about Egyptian.